# Using Tomcat 7 and SuperCSV - in generated and downloaded files non-English characters are all replaced with "?"

Tags: apache, tomcat7, supercsv

What could be causing this, and how can I correct it? The pom.xml includes the line `"<uriEncoding>utf-8</uriEncoding>"`.

Comment: Can you provide more information please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding charset="UTF-8" to the response's content type.